# Changing dataframe column names in R groups at a time

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame (DF) that looks like the following:

```
test <- c('Test1','Test2','Test3')
col.DF.names < c('ID', 'year', 'car', 'age', 'year.1', 'car.1', 'age.1', 'year.2', 'car.2', 'age.2')

ID <- c('A','B','C')

year <- c(2001,2002,2003)
car <- c('acura','benz','lexus')
age <- c(55,16,20)

year.1 <- c(2011,2012,2013)
car.1 <- c('honda','gm','bmw')
age.1 <- c(43,21,34)

year.2 <- c(1961,1962,1963)
car.2 <- c('toyota','porsche','jeep')
age.2 <- c(33,56,42)

DF <- data.frame(ID, year, car, age, year.1, car.1, age.1, year.2, car.2, age.2)
```

I need the columns of data frame to lose the ".#" and instead have the Test# in front of it, so it looks something like this:

```
ID   Test1.year   Test1.car   Test1.age   Test2.year   Test2.car   Test2.age  Test3.year  Test3.car  Test3.age
.... with all the data
```

**Does anyone have a suggestion?**  Basically, starting at the second column, I"d like to add the test[1] name for 3 columns, and then move to the next set of three columns and add test[2] and so on..

I know how to hard code it:

```
colnames(DF)[2:4] <- paste(test[1], colnames(DF)[2:4], sep = ".")
```

but this is a toy set, and I would like to somewhat automate it, so I'm not specifically indicating[2:4] for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

`colnames(DF)[-1] <- paste(sapply(test, rep, 3), colnames(DF)[-1], sep = ".")`

or perhaps the following would be better:

`colnames(DF)[-1] <- paste(sapply(test, rep, 3), colnames(DF)[2:4], sep = ".")`

or:

`colnames(DF)[-1] <- paste(rep(test, each=3), colnames(DF)[2:4], sep = ".")`

thanks to @thelatemail

Comment: Thanks! That's so helpful!  How would i go about removing the .1, and .2 on some of the column names now?

Comment: If they are in fact repeated you could just reuse the first three column names as in my second example.

Comment: The `sapply` is unnecessary. `rep` has an `each=` argument - `paste(rep(test,each=3), names(DF[2:4]), sep=".")`